# Upgrading Craft 3 to 4, deprecation warnings

Tags: upgrades, deprecation

I've just taken over a Craft 3 site that I'm upgrading to Craft 4. I've got 3 updates installed. I'm left with 5 deprecation warnings that are all (except one) coming from deep into the craftcms or yii vendor files. Here is a shot of the warnings...

- The environmentVariables config setting has been renamed to aliases. **Found in:** /var/www/html/config/general.php
- The siteUrl config setting has been deprecated. You can set your site’s Base URL setting on a per-environment basis using an alias or environment variable. See Environmental Configuration for more info. **Found in:** /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php:109
- The environmentVariables config setting has been renamed to aliases. **Found in:** /var/www/html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Config.php:100

There are two more, but they are repeats of the last two.

I did find an environmentVariables array in general.php, but I removed it. I also removed the siteUrl from general.php. But these warnings persist.

Is it important to remove these warnings? If so, any ideas on how to get rid of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I just didn't Clear All on the deprecations page. I assumed when I refreshed the page, it would also refresh the deprecations list. I was wrong, it seems you need to Clear All on the deprecations page to remove past notices. But once I did it removed the warnings. Hope this help someone else.